# MVC5 Changes on Server not being reflected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Whenever I update one of my views on the server, for example if I have the words "Hello World" printed out and then I go change it to "Hi World" it doesn't reflect.

The old text is still there.  The weird part is even if I delete the whole view file the page still loads.  I feel that something is being cached but I do not know what or where to look for it.  On my local machine it all works, in develop and release mode, but on the server when I push the published version of the code, the changes don't take, any help as to why is most appreciated.

This is on a shared host server

EDIT:

If I take all the files and move them to a temp folder, load the site so it crashes, and then move the files back to original location then the changes kick in.

This is not a browser cache, I ensured by deleting any and all history and even loading it on a new browser.

The files are 100% updated because I updated them directly on the server to ensure its not something to do with publishing.

Comment: 1. Check whether it is due to browser caching - try deleting browser cache. 2. Check in server path whether your changes are really getting published - or while publish, select the option to delete files if present already. Most probably this might be caching issue.

Comment: @Developer have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe because of this.
[image]

Comment: The image that you attached does not show for me, do you have a link I can view instead?

Comment: My VS Version is 2013.And I Right click on my project => Publish => Setting => File Publish Option => Check Precompile during publishing => Configure

Comment: Which of the options in the Configure are you referring to?

Comment: That is checked for me